# Regular expression for song name in android

Tags: android

In my application I want to display the song's name. Now it is showing the entire song path, like this

```
String song_name = /storage/Music/Lean on.mp3
```

but I want to display only the song's name, that means

```
String song_name = Lean on.mp3
```

Can any one help me with the regular expressions used for extracting the name of song from the file path?

Comment: See this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use subString function with combination of LastInedexOf function.
please find below example

```
String path=":/storage/Music/Lean on.mp3";
String filename=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```